# How use alert and spinner in same class?

Tags: ios, swift, design-patterns, uialertcontroller, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm using shared class for spinner and alert. It's working but i'm getting crash issues some times.

My code in **SharedClass**

```
import UIKit

class SharedClass: NSObject {

static let sharedInstance = SharedClass()

var transparentView:UIView!
var spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView()

//Show activity indicator
func activityIndicator(view:UIView) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //            if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {//Conditionally unwrap it instead of force unwrap

            //let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow! //Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
            self.transparentView = UIView()
            self.transparentView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
            self.transparentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.4)
            view.addSubview(self.transparentView)

            if UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad {
                self.spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .whiteLarge)
                self.spinner.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 60, height: 60)
            } else {
                self.spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .white)
                self.spinner.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)
            }
            self.spinner.center = view.center
            self.transparentView.addSubview(self.spinner)
            self.spinner.startAnimating()

            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 10.0) {//Stop spinner after 10 Sec's
                self.stopActivityIndicator()
            }
        }
//        }
}

//Stop activity indicator
func stopActivityIndicator() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.spinner.stopAnimating()
        self.spinner.removeFromSuperview()
        self.transparentView.removeFromSuperview()//Some times getting error here
    }
}

//Present alert on top of all windows
func alertWindow(title: String, message: String) {
    //Calling
    //SharedClass.sharedInstance.alertWindow(title:"", message:"")
    DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
        let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window.rootViewController = UIViewController()
        window.windowLevel = UIWindow.Level.alert + 1

        let alert2 = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        let defaultAction2 = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: { action in
        })
        alert2.addAction(defaultAction2)

        window.makeKeyAndVisible()

        window.rootViewController?.present(alert2, animated: true, completion: nil)
    })
}

private override init() {

}

}
```

Some times I'm getting error in this line

```
let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!//Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

self.transparentView.removeFromSuperview()//Some times getting error here
```

How to use properly these two alert and spinner in same class.

Which one is good to use

Write code in shared class or write code in individual class.

Here i write **window** for to display alert and spinner in top of all windows including navigation bar.

Comment: Just from coding practice, you can utilise the same methods under UIViewController extension instead of accessing a shared instance which may led to other several bugs in future.

Comment: @ Sharkes Monken thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `stopActivityIndicator` before `activityIndicator` then `transparentView` will be nil. So don't use implicitly unwrapped optional.

Change

```
var transparentView:UIView!
```

to

```
var transparentView:UIView?
```

and use optional chaining when using this var

```
self.transparentView?.removeFromSuperview()
```

And use guard let to get the key window

```
guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else {
    return
}
```

**UIViewController Extension for Alert**

```
extension UIViewController {
    func showAlert(title: String, msg: String) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: msg, preferredStyle: .alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

You can call this method from any view controller like this. It will present on top of all view and navigation bar.

```
self.showAlert("Alert", msg: "Alert message")
```

Comment: For alert, you can simply create a UIViewController extension method. Why do you get rootViewController from window?

Comment: If I use UIViewController extension in every class to present alert, is it enough to show top of all views including navigation bar.

Answer (score 1):

Do not force unwrap, use `if-let` or `guard`, like so:

```
guard let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }
```

To fix the 2nd error, use optional chaining

```
self.transparentView?.removeFromSuperview()
```

I am using following approach in one of my projects, which is similar to yours, since I use this during network calls, it also enables the NetworkActivity indicator:

```
func showActivityIndicator(inView view: UIView? = nil, isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible: Bool = true) {
    UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible

    guard let target = view ?? UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }

    ...
    let transparentView = UIView()
    // Avoid using self.transparentView here, just use transparentView
    target.addSubview(transparentView)
    self.transparentView = transparentView
}
```

Comment: Your approach is fine to me

Comment: Just a minor improvements, see the update, we using such approach in a large scale project without noticing a bug